# Can we remove the div having the id inside the div class using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="row">
  <div id ="1">Here is content</div>
  <div id ="2">Here is content</div> 
  <div id ="3">Here is content</div>
</div>
<button id ="remove">
```

I want to remove the row form last(3 ,2 ,1) on clicking button using j query please suggest me a code.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service... it is up to you to attempt to solve your own issues and provide any code that isn't working as expected

Comment: $('#remove').click(fucntion(){ var r= document.getElementById('row3'); $('.row').remove(r) ; });

Comment: I think it's better to start the `id or class` to a letter rather than number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click remove button ,get the class `row` and you want to delete its children so use `children()` .Can remove last index by `last()` function and `remove()`.

```
$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('.row').children().last().remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, but I am not sure.  I have assumed that what you want to do is remove the last child of ".row" when you click on the button.

```js
$("#remove").on("click", function(){ $(".row div:last-child").remove(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id ="1">Here is content</div>
  <div id ="2">Here is content</div> 
  <div id ="3">Here is content</div>
</div>
<button id ="remove">remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, IDs can not start with a number, so you should change those.</strike>

But it sounds like this is all you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#three').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="one">Here is content</div>
  <div id="two">Here is content</div>
  <div id="three">Here is content</div>
</div>
<button id="remove">Remove!</div>
```

Comment: *"IDs can not start with a number"* ... not true in html5